# How to use same id multiple times in different div in a single html file

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

But the browser is only considering the first id, i have different buttons in my html file which will work as a pop up form.

Comment: From the [docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes/id): *'The id global attribute defines an identifier (ID) which must be unique in the whole document.'* If you need repeated identifiers use [`class`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes/class).

Comment: Can you explain more about why you want to reuse a div's ID? Ideally you'd instead try to find a way to create unique IDs, or use a class.

Answer (score 1):

Using the same `id` multiple times in a document is not allowed, and is invalid HTML. Look into using [classes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes/class) instead.

Answer (score 0):

You should not use the same id on multiple elements. You could use the same class name and then set the event handler using the shared class instead of an id.

```
$(document).on('click', '.shared-class', function() {
    // prompt your modal
});
```

Answer (score 0):

When I do the web scraping, I notice amazon best seller pages have the same id for multiple  elements, however, it also offers another unique id attribute for its child , I am guessing that if you have a unique id for each child element in one HTML file, it's ok to have some sort of shared id attribute for the parent, although this seems to be against CSS id rules.

Answer (score -1):

You could use `document.querySelectorAll`

```
const allDivs = document.querySelectorAll("#buttons");
allDivs.forEach(div=>{
    div.addEventListener(click,function(){})
})
```

Comment: This does work but like others have said you shouldn't be reusing ID's